# PCSC reader emulator

Tags: c, linux, pcsc

I need an software emulator PC/SC reader for Linux, but can't find.

The only thing I found is http://vsmartcard.sourceforge.net/. But this library requires a mobile phone to emulate PC / SC device.

Can I find somewhere fully software emulator of PC/SC reader?
Thank you for you attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided is the answer to your question.
The project proposed on that link is the Virtual Smart Card Architecture which can be used to simulate smart cards for different purposes. You do not require a mobile phone, that is just one use case scenario they present.

http://vsmartcard.sourceforge.net/virtualsmartcard/README.html
Following this instructions you can access three smart card simulators provided by them. Besides this you can also hack their python virtual card and implement/simulate your desired behaviour.

Comment: Didn't see the date of the question. I suppose this isn't helpfull anymore :P